# Get random point from django PolygonField

Tags: python, postgis, geodjango, django

**TL,DR**; *I want to get a random point from a polygon (potentially) using [ST_GeneratePoints](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeneratePoints.html).*

---

**Background**

I'm making a GeoDjango webservice and have a collection of UK Postcodes with respective boundaries like so:

```
from django.db import models as dj_models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models

class Postcode(gis_models.Model):
      pretty_postcode = dj_models.CharField( max_length=8 )
      coords = gis_models.PolygonField( default='POLYGON EMPTY' )
```

I've found a delightful little PostGis function [ST_GeneratePoints](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeneratePoints.html), it can find me random points in my `coords` region.

**Your Challenge**

Your mission if you so choose it, is to show how to use this function from within my python django app (or suggest a better way). Ideally ending up with a function like so:

```
from django.contrib.gis import geos
# ... other imports ...

class Postcode(gis_models.Model):
     # ... fields ...

     def get_random_point(self):
         rand_point = # code that executes ST_GeneratePoints
                      # and returns a geos.Point instance
         return rand_point
```

Comment: Can you not just pass `self.coords` to `ST_GeneratePoints`?

Comment: I would love to, how do I achieve that?

Comment: I have created an answer to the same question in StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455081/get-random-point-from-django-polygonfield/46464362#46464362

Answer (score 0):

You can execute raw sql using a connection cursor. Something along the lines of the snippet below (which I have not tested, so it might not work 1:1 as it is shown)

```
from django.db import connection

def get_random_point(self):
    # Return only one point in the geometry.
    npoints = 1
    # Prepare sql command, return point as ewkt, passing the 
    # bounding geometry as ewkt.
    sql = 'SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_GeneratePoints(ST_GeomFromEWKT({ewkt}), npoints))'
    # Instanciate cursor.
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # Inject coords into sql command and execute sql.
    cursor.execute(sql.format(ewkt=self.coords.ewkt))
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    # Convert result to python geometry.
    return OGRGeometry(row[0])
```